# What is the result of attaching a lambda expresstion to the main method of a C# program?

Tags: c#, lambda, syntax, delegates, roslyn

In short, I'd like to know why the following code compiles and runs.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) => Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

My limited knowledge of C# is telling me that a Delegate with the name of Main is created, and for some reason the compiler/runtime accepts this Delegate as a valid starting point for the program. Is my understanding correct?  Is there a specific reason a statement like this would be used?

I came across this looking at the Roslyn source code, found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/csc/Program.cs).

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft.  All Rights Reserved.  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0.  See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine;
using Roslyn.Utilities;
using System;

namespace Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
            => Main(args, Array.Empty<string>());

        public static int Main(string[] args, string[] extraArgs)
            => DesktopBuildClient.Run(args, extraArgs, RequestLanguage.CSharpCompile, Csc.Run, new DesktopAnalyzerAssemblyLoader());

        public static int Run(string[] args, string clientDir, string workingDir, string sdkDir, string tempDir, TextWriter textWriter, IAnalyzerAssemblyLoader analyzerLoader)
            => Csc.Run(args, new BuildPaths(clientDir: clientDir, workingDir: workingDir, sdkDir: sdkDir, tempDir: tempDir), textWriter, analyzerLoader);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static void Main(string[] args) => Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

is not a delegate because there is no `delegate` keyword. It's just a method/function. The way it's written is just a shorthand way of writing simple methods/functions, introduced in C# 6. It is called expression bodied function. See [C# : The New and Improved C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx).

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.